# Removing the third dimension in SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, raster, r-sp

I have a SpatialPoints object with 3 dimensions :

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
y <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
z <- c(1,3,5,2,1,2,1,2,3)
xyz <- cbind(x,y,z)
ss <- SpatialPoints(xyz)
dimensions(ss)
```

And a `raster` object:

```
rr <- raster(matrix(round(runif(49,0,10)),7,7), xmn=0, xmx=4, ymn=0, ymx=4, crs=NA, template=NULL)
```

I want to extract the raster values using the `SpatialPoints` object:

```
 extract(rr,ss)
#Error in .xyValues(x, coordinates(y), ..., df = df) : 
#  xy should have 2 columns only.
#Found these dimensions: 9, 3
```

You can visualize the data if you want:

```
plot(rr)
plot(ss, add=T)
```

So the problem is that the `extract` function of the raster package require a 2 dimension SpatialPoints object.  Mine (in my real data) in 3 dimensional.  Is there a way to drop the 3rd dimension of my point shape?  I've tried:

```
coordinates(ss) <- coordinates(ss)[,-3]
#Error in `coordinates<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,  : 
#  setting coordinates cannot be done on Spatial objects, where they have #already been set
```

I don't want to have to rebuild my shape from scratch.

Comment: are you looking for this: ss@coords[, 1:2]?

Comment: @MLavois, what you say gives me the two dimension as a matrix (which is the same as my :`coordinates(ss)[,-3]`), it's not what I want, I want a new shape object but with only 2 dimension, not three.  Keeping all the rest the same (data, projection, etc.)

Comment: Just overwrite the `coords` slot: `ss@coords <- ss@coords[, 1:2]`

Comment: @rcs That was easy...  it makes sense that `ss@coords <- ss@coords[, 1:2]` works instead of `coordinates(ss) <- coordinates(ss)[,1:2]`.  I should have pushed further that road...  You can add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just overwrite the `coords` slot of the S4 object:

```
ss@coords <- ss@coords[, 1:2]
```

---

I don't know how your `SpatialPoints` object is created, but if you use `rgdal::readOGR` there is a `pointDropZ` argument (default `FALSE`)

Comment: The `pointDropZ` argument is also a good solution I wasn't aware off.  I'll use that one as I'm using `readOGR`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@rcs answer is better, but this works as well:

```
ss <- SpatialPoints(coordinates(ss)[,-3])
```

and if you have a SpatialPointsDataFrame:

```
ss <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coordinates(ss)[,-3], ss@data,proj4string=CRS(proj4string(ss)))
```